# Splitting the string by few delimeter

Tags: c#, string

I have a string with me and I want to call a rest method from that string. Can anyone think of a better approach then the one I described below for converting str to Rest Call Url.

```
str : https://P1.P2.com/ProjectName/_build?definitionId=123
Extract P1 and ProjectName and definitionId

Rest Call : https://dev.azure.com/P1/ProjectName/_apis/pipelines/123/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1

Here, after getting the string, split it with "//" and then split array[1] with "/" and then get P1, ProjectName and then find something with "=" and then the number ?
```

Not sure if this might be ok.

**Update :**
I can get this as a URI. But how to convert it then ?

Comment: Use the [`Uri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?viw=net-6.0) class, it is specifically there to help with parsing things like this.

Comment: Yes, I can get this as a URI. But how to convert it then ?

Comment: What do you mean by "convert it then"?

Comment: Like how to get only P1 from P1.P2.com, how to get 123. Do I split it for P1 ?

Comment: For the query string, use [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Did you even read the link I shared? It explains in great detail how to do just about everything you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, use [`Uri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-uri-ctor(system-string)) to parse out the host, path, and query parts of the URI:

```
var uri = new Uri("https://P1.P2.com/ProjectName/_build?definitionId=123");
```

For extracting `P1` from the host, it's probably going to be easiest to split on `.`:

```
string subdomain = uri.Host.Split('.')[0]
```

For `ProjectName`, just look at [`uri.Segments`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.segments?view=net-6.0):

```
string projectName = uri.Segments[1];
```

For `definitionId`, parse the query string with [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring?view=net-6.0):

```
var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
string definitionId = query["definitionId"];
```

To construct the new Uri, use a [`UriBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder?view=net-6.0):

```
var builder = new UriBuilder()
{
    Scheme = "https",
    Host = "dev.azure.com",
    Path = $"{subdomain}/{projectName}_apis/pipelines/{definitionId}/runs",
    Query = "api-version=6.0-preview.1",
};
string result = builder.ToString();
```

[See it on dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/djsHBE)

Comment: Thank you. I have a Uri for Host defined at some place. so when I do `Host = baseUri.ToString()`. I get the output as `http://[dev.azure.com]/P1/ProjectName/_apis/pipelines/123/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1`. "[] bracket gets added". Also it is http and not https.

Comment: @Newbie I've fixed the `https`, see the edit. I'm going to guess that `baseUri.ToString()` returns `[dev.azure.com]` then? That's not something that's in your question. If this answer answers the question you asked in your question (which doesn't mention `baseUri`), please mark it as the accepted answer